# Kafka Streams Twitter Wordcount - Count Value not Long after Serialization

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, long-integer, word-count

I am running a Kafka Cluster Docker Compose on an AWS EC2 instance.
I want to receive all the tweets of a specific keyword and push them to Kafka. This works fine.
But I also want to count the most used words of those tweets.

This is the WordCount code:

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Materialized;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import static org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG;
import static org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG;
import static org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG;
import static org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG;

public class WordCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        final KStream<String, String> textLines = builder
                .stream("test-topic");

        textLines
                .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
                .groupBy((key, value) -> value)
                .count(Materialized.as("WordCount"))
                .toStream()
                .to("test-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));

        final Topology topology = builder.build();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-word-count");
        props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "ec2-ip:9092");
        props.put(DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
                new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        streams.close();
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                });
        try {
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

When I check the output topic in the Control Center, it looks like this:

[Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z2l5.png)

[Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9co4b.png)

Looks like it's working as far as splitting the tweets into single words. But the count value isn't in Long format, although it is specified in the code.

When I use the kafka-console-consumer to consume from this topic, it says:

"Size of data received by LongDeserializer is not 8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control Center UI and console consumer can only render UTF8 data, by default.

You'll need to explicitly pass LongDeserializer to the console consumer, as the value deserializer only

Comment: Thank you! Forgot to put the right value for the value deserializer in the command. It works with console consumer and --property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer

Answer (score -1):

try a KTable instead:

```
KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("test-topic", Consumed.with(stringSerde, stringSerde));

KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines    
    .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+")))
    .groupBy((key, value) -> value)    
    .count()
    .toStream()
    .to("test-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
```

Comment: .count() already is used in the question, and already creates a table